# jQuery redirect inside ajax in case page not found

Tags: jquery, ajax

When using `jQuery` and `Ajax`, I pass the entire URL to ajax's `url:` In case that `URL` weren't there (somehow), how could I redirect to a `page not found` page from inside `ajax` itself? The `url` go thru and `.htaccess` file.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.link').click(function () {
    var parentTag = 'check=checked';
    if(parentTag) {
        // ajax call
        $.ajax({
            type:"GET",
            url:"/mylink/buyers/1/0/0", //If this failed, how do I redirect to something else from here?
            data:parentTag,
        dataType: 'json',
            beforeSend:function(callBack){
                console.log('checked');
            },
            success: function(callBack){
                console.log('Success');
            },
            error: function(callBack){
                console.log('Failed');
            },
        });
    }
    return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Isn't that what the `error` callback does? You can find the http response code with `this.status` probably (or log `this` and you'll see).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a [statusCode](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) handler for a 404, or any other [HTTP status](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) you want!

You could also add a generic error callback, but the advantage of using the status code method is distinguishing between actual 404s (page not found errors) from the server and other kinds of connectivity problems.

```
$.ajax({
  /* ... */
 statusCode: {
    404: function() {
         // server says: page not found; let's redirect to 404 page
         window.location.href = "http://example.com/my/404/page";
    }
  },
  error: function() {
      // something else went wrong
      alert('An unknown error occurred!');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Just put `window.location` inside error callback:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.link').click(function () {
    var parentTag = 'check=checked';
    if(parentTag) {
        // ajax call
        $.ajax({
            type:"GET",
            url:"/mylink/buyers/1/0/0", //If this failed, how do I redirect to something else from here?
            data:parentTag,
        dataType: 'json',
            beforeSend:function(callBack){
                console.log('checked');
            },
            success: function(callBack){
                console.log('Success');
            },
            error: function(callBack){
                console.log('Failed');
                window.location = "http://www.example.com";
            },
        });
    }
    return false;
    });
});
```